# Vector dot product equation

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

if $a\cdot b=a\cdot c$ and $a$ is not $0$,

Is $b = c$?

How should the solution be? I have to prove.

Comment: You could take $\vec{a}=\hat i + \hat j$, $\vec{b} =  \hat{j}$ and $\vec{c} = \hat j$, and you have a counter-example.

Comment: @MattiP.:  Did you mean $\vec b= \hat i$ or something like that?  With what you wrote, $\vec b=\vec c$, which is not a counterexample

Comment: Yes, a simple typo. I wrote it so fast that I didn't notice. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\vec a\cdot \vec b=\vec a\cdot \vec c$, then $\vec a \cdot (\vec b-\vec c)=0$.  That means $\vec a\perp \vec b-\vec c$.

It does not necessarily mean $\vec b-\vec c=\vec 0$.

For example, $(0,1)\cdot(1,0)=(0,1)\cdot(2,0)$, but $(1,0)\ne(2,0)$.

Comment: yes b-c = 0, so b=c right?

Comment: it does not mean $\vec b - \vec c =\vec 0$.  I added an example

Comment: thanks man ı got it!